# JS average calc

Tags: javascript, math, average

I'm trying to create a site that calculates the annual average grade of someone in a certain subject. But, when clicking the button "Calculate", it returns "[object HTMLHeadingElement][object HTMLHeadingElement][object HTMLHeadingElement][object HTMLHeadingElement][object HTMLHeadingElement]NaN". What's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <head>
        <title>Annual Average Grade</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Calculate your annual average grade."/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="../favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="../favicons/site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="../favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicons/favicon.ico">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="../favicons/mstile-144x144.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-config" content="../favicons/browserconfig.xml">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    </head>
    <style>
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        }
        a, b {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        }
        button {
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            background-color: white;
        }
        input {
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            border-color: black;
            border-width: 1px;
            height: 25px;
        }
        .align-left {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .align-center {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .align-right {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .title {
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        .description {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: lighter;
        }
        .subtitle {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        .grade {
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title" style="margin-left: 15px">Annual Average Grade</h1>
        <h2 class="description" style="margin-top: -20px">Calculate your annual average grade.</h2>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h3 class="subtitle">Mathematics</h3>
        <div class="grade">
        <h4 id="first-grade">1st grade:</h3><input type="number"/>
        <h4 id="second-grade">2nd grade:</h3><input type="number"/>
        <h4 id="third-grade">3rd grade:</h3><input type="number"/>
        <h4 id="fourth-grade">4th grade:</h3><input type="number"/>
        <h4 id="fifth-grade">5th grade</h3><input type="number"/>
        <h4 id="sixth-grade">6th grade:</h3><input type="number"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="align-center">
        <button onclick="calcGradeAverage()">Calculate</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            function calcGradeAverage() {
                var firstGrade = document.getElementById('first-grade');
                var secondGrade = document.getElementById('second-grade');
                var thirdGrade = document.getElementById('third-grade');
                var fourthGrade = document.getElementById('fourth-grade');
                var fifthGrade = document.getElementById('fifth-grade');
                var sixthGrade = document.getElementById('sixth-grade');
                var res = firstGrade + secondGrade + thirdGrade + fourthGrade + fifthGrade + sixthGrade / 6;
                document.write(res);
         }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're retrieving the headings, not the inputs.

Comment: @j08691 How can I retrieve the inputs?

Comment: The easiest way would be to move the IDs from the heading to the inputs. Then you could do `parseInt( document.getElementById('first-grade').value, 10); ...` which would return the integer value of the string being input.

Answer (score 1):

You're calculating your grades with the hmtl-objects. you need to get the value out of there (with .value() )

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with the one below : I will explain why.

Explanation (I will explain in a verrrrry simplified way ;-) ):

*For us to see the results of our calculation , we need to calculate the average of the grades

*For us to calculate the average of grades , we need to first have the grades

*For us to have the grades , we need values from the forms

*For us to have the values , we need to access the HTML DOM

The way to access the DOM elements is this way

```
    document.getElementById('myid');
```

The way to access values in a DOM element is this way

```
    document.getElementById('myid').value;
```

*So in HTML , I took the id="" from `<h3>` and placed it in `<input>` tags
*Then in JavaScript , I called the values inputted by the user .

Thats all .

```
 <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="pt-br">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <head>
        <title>Annual Average Grade</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Calculate your annual average grade."/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="../favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="../favicons/site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="../favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicons/favicon.ico">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="../favicons/mstile-144x144.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-config" content="../favicons/browserconfig.xml">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    </head>
    <style>
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        }
        a, b {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        }
        button {
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            background-color: white;
        }
        input {
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            border-color: black;
            border-width: 1px;
            height: 25px;
        }
        .align-left {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .align-center {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .align-right {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .title {
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        .description {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: lighter;
        }
        .subtitle {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        .grade {
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title" style="margin-left: 15px">Annual Average Grade</h1>
        <h2 class="description" style="margin-top: -20px">Calculate your annual average grade.</h2>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h3 class="subtitle">Mathematics</h3>
        <div class="grade">
        <h3 >1st grade:</h3><input type="number" id="first-grade" />
        <h3 >2nd grade:</h3><input type="number" id="second-grade" />
        <h3 >3rd grade:</h3><input type="number" id="third-grade" />
        <h3 >4th grade:</h3><input type="number" id="fourth-grade" />
        <h3 >5th grade:</h3><input type="number" id="fifth-grade" />
        <h3 >6th grade:</h3><input type="number" id="sixth-grade" />
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="align-center">
        <button onclick="calcGradeAverage()">Calculate</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            function calcGradeAverage() {
                var firstGrade = document.getElementById('first-grade').value;
                var secondGrade = document.getElementById('second-grade').value;
                var thirdGrade = document.getElementById('third-grade').value;
                var fourthGrade = document.getElementById('fourth-grade').value;
                var fifthGrade = document.getElementById('fifth-grade').value;
                var sixthGrade = document.getElementById('sixth-grade').value;
                var res = firstGrade + secondGrade + thirdGrade + fourthGrade + fifthGrade + sixthGrade / 6;
                document.write(res);
         }
         /*
         Explanation (I will explain in a verrrrry simplified way ;-) ):

         *For us to see the results of our calculation , we need to calculate the average of the grades
         *For us to calculate the average of grades , we need to first have the grades
         *For us to have the grades , we need values from the forms
         *For us to have the values , we need to access the HTML DOM

         The way to access the DOM elements is this way

            document.getElementById('myid')

         The way to access values in a DOM element is this way

            document.getElementById('myid').value

          *So in HTML , I took the id="" from <h3> and placed it in <input> tags
          *Then in JavaScript , I called the values inputted by the user .

          Thats all .
         */
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put .value

```
var firstGrade = document.getElementById('first-grade').value;
var secondGrade = document.getElementById('second-grade').value;
var thirdGrade = document.getElementById('third-grade').value;
var fourthGrade = document.getElementById('fourth-grade').value;
var fifthGrade = document.getElementById('fifth-grade').value;
var sixthGrade = document.getElementById('sixth-grade').value;
```

It is also good practice to write a doctype like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

although it is not required.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the post. Please upvote, because I am a new member.